# How do I make iPhone vibrate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using this code buy getting compile errors for the audio line.  Does anyone know why?

```
- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer 
{
    self.counter--;
    self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", self.counter];
    if (self.counter == 0)
    {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
}
```

Comment: The errors are very helpful in debugging your problem, always paste them with your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely forgot to import a framework for it

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```